# How to generate an excel file from a PowerQuery query via java?

Tags: java, excel, powerquery

I am generating a metaquery created with the `PowerQuery` syntax, and I would like to use some library to generate an excel file from there.
I have tried `POI` and `Docx4j` with no success. Any advice would be helpfull.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have not explained what you tried and what failed. Please explain what you tried and were it did not work.

Comment: Of course, excuse me. I have tried to find an API for passing a PowerQuery query to a new Workbook created in Java with the libraries i mention (POI and Docx4j), and this way, generating the excel with the queries result but these libraries have no support for powerquery or something similar, also i havent found any library that supports this kind of querys.
Im trying to accomplish it by using automation from java, but its not the way i would like to resolve it. Its ugly and involves using things from outside Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VBA to automate creating queries in Excel 2016 https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/VBA-to-automate-Power-956a52d1

Maybe you could use java to send a message to some VBA running in the Excel workbook, or to generate some VBA script that runs when you open the workbook, and have the VBA actually create the query?

---

Edu says: store the query in the windows clipboard and then generate the query via VBA in excel with a macro.

Comment: This is the way we solved it, there is not much documentation about it but its not that hard either...we basically store the query in the windows clipboard and then generate the query via VBA in excel with a macro.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any Java libraries that can add Power Query queries to an Excel file. The structure inside of the Excel file is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt577248(v=office.12).aspx), so you could implement yourself, or request a library developer to implement it.

Comment: I am trying to do it by dividing the xml into its smaller parts and replacing the code there by my own, but is really a hard task and not so good by the "developing" point of view.